# C2694 on destructor when base class' member's destructor has non-empty noexcept specifier and a body

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am experiencing a compiler error that I can't explain and have not been able to find information online about it. I've recently added a `noexcept` specifier to the destructor of a wrapper class and now a large number of classes which inherit from classes that use this wrapper are failing to compile. I've tried it with GCC 4.9 without compiler error.

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2015 version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Consider the following minimal code which reproduces the problem :

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct member
{
    ~member() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value) {};
};

struct parent
{ 
    virtual ~parent() noexcept = default;
};


struct derived : public parent
{
    member<int> x;
};
```

The snippet produces the following error message :

```
1>c:\users\fandrieux\workspace\tmp\dtor_noexcept\main.cpp(19): error C2694: 'derived::~derived(void) noexcept(<expr>)': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'parent::~parent(void) noexcept'
1>  c:\users\fandrieux\workspace\tmp\dtor_noexcept\main.cpp(19): note: compiler has generated 'derived::~derived' here
1>  c:\users\fandrieux\workspace\tmp\dtor_noexcept\main.cpp(12): note: see declaration of 'parent::~parent'
```

What I find interesting is that the compiler error disappears if you replace member's destructor body by `= default` or use either `noexcept` or `noexcept(true)` :

```
// None of these produce compiler errors
virtual ~member() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value) = default;
virtual ~member() noexcept(true) {}
virtual ~member() noexcept {}
```

I know that it's destructor does not throw. Paranoids and skeptics (like me) can add the following static assert and it check themselves :

```
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value, "Might throw!");
```

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x95xf8.aspx) it signals an insufficient dynamic exception specifier. How does this apply here? Isn't `noexcept([boolean expression])` equivalent to either `noexcept(true)` or `noexcept(false)`? Why does this change depending on the presence of a function body? Adding an explicit noexcept destructor to derived gets ride of the compiler error, but this feels like an unnecessary workaround. In practice it's also quite a burden when you consider that every derived class would have to be updated.

Comment: Let the upvotes speak for themselves, but this is a great question. Thank you, and good luck

Comment: Fwiw, in addition to gcc 4.9, this also passes muster through clang 3.8 under language-level c++14 with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: I'm sure the question *could* be improved - but I think we would be better worrying about the 999 poorer questions in the last 1000 asked first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a compiler bug. If we add the following class:

```
struct dtor_throws
{
    ~dtor_throws() noexcept(false) {}
};
```

And change the definition of `derived` thusly:

```
struct derived : public parent
{
    member<dtor_throws> x;
};
```

Then GCC and Clang both complain that the exception specification of `~derived` is looser than `~parent`.

In the original example, MSVC appears not to be embedding the *value* of the `noexcept` expression in the type of `~parent`, but merely treating all compound `noexcept` specifications of user-defined destructors of class templates as being more relaxed than `noexcept(true)`.

MSVC 2017 RC is also affected.